# JavaScript Design Pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am working on a chat room application in JavaScript using websockets. However, aside from the small snippets of jQuery here and there, I have very little experience with JavaScript.

My question is, what design pattern should I use to make an object self contained and to be able to create multiple instances of it without interfering with other instances of the same object? Also, I need to know how I can store public object properties and access them from within event handlers when the 'this' keyword refers to something other than the current objects instance.

Code examples would be great!

Currently, I'm using the prototype design pattern and it seems to be working but isn't very elegant - to say the least... Especially with how I'm handling events, is there a better way?

I am currently doing something like:

```
function Room( args ) {
    this.container = $( '#room-' + args.id );
    this.container.find( '.someBtn' ).on( 'click', this.someEventHandler() );
}

Room.prototype.someEventHandler = function() {
    var self = this;

    return function( event ) {
        console.log( self, this, event );
    }
}
```

Comment: a lot of questions - you're probably better off spending a few hours reading a good JS book, such as: http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742

Comment: @tjdecke the book has nothing about design patterns

Comment: Why haven't you investigated socket.io and node.js ? There are many examples in doing this and open source ones that will answer your questions and you can just move forward much quicker. Here's just one of many -> https://github.com/ericraio/socket.io-chat-demo

Comment: @Esailija while it is not a book on design patterns, it certainly has it's fair share of code-reuse patterns - as such, it might clear up confusion of inheritance aspects (visibility, alternatives to prototypal inheritance), which he seems to be interested in

Comment: @zipstory.com Sorry if I wasn't clear, I'm actually using SmartFoxServer for the low-level stuff and backend. I'm simply building the presentation layer (so-to-speak), the high-level client-side application in JS while making use of their available API.

I had actually looked at using (Backbone, Underscore, Require).js, and jQuery to make a single-page application as it would fit my project perfectly. However, I found myself unable to really grasp the concepts with my current level of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The prototype is good enough and it works great for the task you've described.

If you want more you can't escape from reading :-)
There are many design patterns out there, and sometimes it's more a matter of preference because the differences are small.

Here's one of the best readings about patterns: [JS Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/)

and another one about module patterns and requirejs: [organising code using modules](http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you don't leave it to Room to figure out the element and use $.proxy

```
function Room( args ) {
    this.container = $( args.elem ); //elem can be selector, dom element, or another jQuery object
    this.container.find( '.someBtn' ).on( 'click', $.proxy( this.clicked, this) );
}

Room.prototype.clicked = function(event) {
    console.log( this, event.currentTarget );
}
```

In the `clicked` method `this` is the room instance abd
        `event.currentTarget` is the element the handler is attached on or the delegated target. See http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/

I have a pending feature request for jQuery to make the above even cleaner http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12031

Comment: Are there any advantages to proxy? Why would I use it? Is proxy faster than returning an anon function?

Comment: @user1960364 isn't it obvious? The `.clicked` function is reduced to a one-liner, where as it was 4 lines in your current code

Comment: Unfortunately, just because it's fewer lines of code does not mean it's more efficient... I just don't want to make sure I'm not adding a lot of overhead in exchange for simply being lazy and typing fewer lines. :)

Comment: @user1960364 This question was about design patterns and suddenly you are ready to duplicate code everywhere to gain nano performance optimizations? :P No it doesn't affect performance at all. It's just a helper function to do what you would otherwise be doing manually every time.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Haha! I always try to learn best practices from the get-go. That's what this topic is really about. :D My undying need for perfection in a very imperfect world. lol